# Is iOS Keychain service different from iCloud keychain?

Tags: ios, icloud, keychain

I have been reading the document, but I am getting confused.

There is iOS Keychain [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW3).

And there is iCloud Keychain [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204085).

They both called keychain and both able to store locally and sync to other devices.
Are they just the same thing?
Or iOS keychain service doesn't require iCloud account for local storage at all?

Answer (score 1):

iOS Keychain is a service which allows you to persist user-sensitive information in your application.

iCloud Keychain is a service provided by Apple which syncs your Safari passwords as well as Mail, Contacts, Calendar, and Messages synced across all of the devices signed in with a specific Apple ID.